# How to decode encodeURIComponent in PHP without integers turning into strings

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode, urldecode

In my Javascript code, I form my query like so:

```
    let query = "needleKey=" + encodeURIComponent(needle.key)
    query += "&needleValue=" + encodeURIComponent(needle.value);
    query += "&newData=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(newData));

    fetch(API, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
        }),
        body: query
    })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(response => {
            resolve(response.text());
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("ERR: Error fetching " + API + query + "\n" + err);
            reject(err);
        });
```

I collect this on the back end with the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['needleKey']) && isset($_REQUEST['needleValue'])) {
    $needleKey = $_REQUEST['needleKey'];
    $needleValue = $_REQUEST['needleValue'];
    
    $filter = [$needleKey => $needleValue];
} else {
    echo "ERR: No needle passed to DB server.";
    return;
}
```

My issue is that if `needle.value` in the javascript code is a integer (ie: `1234`) it ends up as the string `'1234'` in the PHP code.   I have tried converting the string to an int in PHP (and it works) but I don't want to blindly convert ALL `needleValues` to integers because I have occasion where I want to be able to pass a number as a string.

I tried adding rawurldecode to the php code to no success.  I've also tried a few different ways of forming the query in javascript, to no avail.

How can I pass a number from javascript to PHP and have it stay a number?

Comment: You can't, http(s) is a textual data transfer protocol. You've to cast the string to a number in PHP, in a way or another.

Comment: Your server should know what type a certain parameter is supposed to be and cast them accordingly, which should also serve as input validation.

Comment: Great point, @deceze.  I was trying to build the endpoint to be very generic -- but by limiting it and doing the validation checks, it'll be more secure.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you have to use JSON.stringify:

```js
query += "&needleValue=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(needle.value));
```

Then in PHP decode it:

```php
$needleValue = json_decode($_REQUEST['needleValue']);
```

I'm not sure if this works, but you can try it.